# Can I access profile picture folder of contacts in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone, contacts

For any contact in people hub having a profile picture, the picture is saved in 'Profile Picture' folder.
Is it possible to access this profile picture folder for a particular contact using code and somehow  place a photo in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Are you trying to change the profile picture of a contact? On Windows Phone you have read only access to system contacts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i was trying to change the profile picture of a contact.